# For a shared resource accessed by two threads, how to arrange priority?

Tags: java

Is there a way to give one thread priority over another when accessing the resource?

Comment: can you elaborate on the problem you are trying to solve ?

Answer (score 3):

No, and simply speaking: it makes no sense. Unless both threads try to get the ressource at EXACTLY the same time (very rare) a priority wont help, unless th thread with higher priority can "steal" the ressource already in use.

Basically you can never have more than one item waiting, so what use is a priority? With 3+ threads it makes logical sense, with 2 it is simply without any benefit.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by there can never be more than one item waiting. What item ?

Comment: Thread. With 2 threads and one ressource the waiting list will never be longer than one item. Unless the waiting thread can steal the resource it makes NO SENSE to have priorities for a list with length 1.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use `setPriority(int)` method of Thread class.

Ex:-

```
Threadt = new Thread(this);
t.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY);
```

Comment: You can set it, but the OS is free to ignore this. Even if the OS honours this hint, there is no guarantee you will see any change in behaviour. If you have free CPU, any thread which want to run, can run regardless of priority.  In a CPU limited system esp one core, this can make a difference to mow much CPU is available, but only indirectly controls access to shared resources.

Comment: Setting of Thread Priority to higher value , can help when used with Thread's yield() method.

Answer (score 0):

use the following code in thread class

```
Thread threadB = new Thread(makeRunnable(), "threadB");
threadB.setPriority(2);
```

or visit link below
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Threads/SetThreadPriority.htm

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are seeking a solution where if a Thread (H) with high priority wants to access a resource, then if another thread (L) with lower priority is accessing it, you want to stop it or make it release the resource.

If that is the case, then you will have to either send a message to L via a method call or the thread L will have to keep checking some flag value that can be set by thread H, when it wants to access the resource. Thread L can then release the resource and wait for some time before trying to use the resource again.